# Same Column, Same Table - Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    [SSI$Sales Price].[Sales Code] AS CUSTOMER
    ,[SSI$Sales Price].[Sales Code] AS SRP
    ,[SSI$Sales Price].[Item No_] AS [Item No]
    ,[SSI$Sales Price].[Variant Code]
    ,[SSI$Sales Price].[Unit of Measure Code] AS [Unit of Measure]
    ,[SSI$Sales Price].[Unit Price] AS SALES1
    ,[SSI$Sales Price].[Unit Price] AS SALES2
    ,SSI$Item.[Unit Cost]
    ,[SSI$Sales Price].[Starting Date]
    ,[SSI$Sales Price].[Ending Date]


FROM [SSI$Sales Price]

LEFT JOIN SSI$Item
    ON [SSI$Sales Price].[Item No_] = SSI$Item.No_

JOIN [SSI$Sales Price] AS CUSTOMER
    ON [SSI$Sales Price].[Item No_] = [SSI$Sales Price].[Item No_] AND [SSI$Sales Price].[Variant Code] = [SSI$Sales Price].[Variant Code] 

JOIN [SSI$Sales Price] AS SRP
    ON [SSI$Sales Price].[Item No_] = [SSI$Sales Price].[Item No_] AND [SSI$Sales Price].[Variant Code] = [SSI$Sales Price].[Variant Code] 

WHERE
    [SSI$Sales Price].[Sales Code] = 'C00020' AND
    [SSI$Sales Price].[Sales Code] = 'SRP' AND
    [SSI$Sales Price].[Sales Type] = '0'
```

While running the above i get no results.

Bellow is a sample data and expected results.

Table1

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
 A     Item1   100
 A     Item2   200
 A     Item3   300
 B     Item1   400
 B     Item2   500
 B     Item3   600
```

---

SQL Query Result

```
  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
 Item1     A      100      B       400
 Item2     A      200      B       500 
 Item3     A      300      B       600
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is the question?

Comment: good day, the above sql query code. after i run the query nothing happen / no error message. im trying to attached a picture of the scenario but its im not yet authorized to upload imeages since im new here in the forum. thank you.

Comment: how do your "expected" `SQL Query Result` and `Table1` relate to the query you posted? neither the number of columns nor the names of columns seem to match.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.col2 as col1,a.col1 as col2,a.col3 as col3,b.col1 as col4,b.col3 as col5
(select col1,col2,col3 from table where col1='A')a
join
(select col1,col2,col3 from table where col1='B')b
on a.col1=b.col1
```

This is the sample, formulate inner queries with required filters.

Comment: thanks for the reply. sorry but i cant follow your sample code.

Comment: For the sample Table1 and the expected result you can use the code directly.I am not able to understand your goal from the main select statement.
Remove all the alias names and try going through it.

Comment: hi, i remove all the alias but still got no result.